# How long is the tutorial campaign?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Are there really just 2 missions? It seemed pretty abrupt and there was no indication that the campaign ended after "Emperor's Will".

Comment: Yeah, I thought this was pretty abrupt too, but Murgatroid99 is correct. There's no "campaign score screen" like in previous games.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no direct indication that the two missions are the only ones, but once those two missions are completed, all of the other campaigns unlock, which would indicate that the tutorial is complete.

Comment: A little bad design on their part I guess. That's a bit confusing

Comment: I agree. I was also confused when there just weren't any other missions until I noticed that the other campaigns were unlocked.